# Adding y label to dendextend dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, dendextend

How can I add a y label to a dendrogram produced by `dendextend`? This may be used to label "Pairwise Distance", for example.

What about for horizontal (`ggplot(horiz = T)`) dendrograms?

Answer (score 1):

`axis.title.y` must be specified in a theme for the text to show up. For example:

```
dend %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  labs(y = "Pairwise Euclidean Distance") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90))
```

For horizontal dendrograms, `y` is specified to `labs()`, but now we need `axis.title.x` in `theme()`. I could only get text to show up by specifying `color = "black"`. Not sure why.

```
dend %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  labs(y = "Pairwise Euclidean Distance") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black"))
```